# zsh: parse error near `&&' when in macOS monterey

Tags: macos, shell, oh-my-zsh

when I using this command in macOS terminal:

```
export PUB_HOSTED_URL=https://pub.flutter-io.cn \ 
&& export FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL=https://storage.flutter-io.cn \
&& ~/fvm/versions/2.10.3/bin/flutter run -v
```

the terminal output shows error like this:

```
➜  cruise-open git:(main) ✗ export PUB_HOSTED_URL=https://pub.flutter-io.cn \
&& export FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL=https://storage.flutter-io.cn \
&& ~/fvm/versions/2.10.3/bin/flutter run -v
zsh: parse error near `&&'
```

why did this happen? what should I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: Are there spaces after any of the ```\``` characters that're supposed to be at the end of lines? Also, why are you joining the commands together with `&&` at all, instead of just running them as three separate commands?

Comment: You have to remove the space after the first backslash.